# Is it possible to get the user's terminal preferences?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, terminal

I am trying to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as a way to escape the CLI, though, due to the fact that my terminal preferences assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to the Copy function, I need to type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to escape the CLI.

Using Python, I would like to detect and alter exiting the CLI with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is occupied. So, is there a way to access a user's terminal preferences in order to properly change the utility of a key combination?

Comment: Can’t you change keyboard preference key map?

Comment: @danglingpointer The aim is to adjust the escape functionality, based on the user's terminal settings. So, instead of pointing out 'Ctrl+C' as an escape keyboard combination to the end-user, indicate 'Shift+Ctrl+C'.

Comment: How is your Python script handling EOF? You could advise the user to press 'Ctrl+D', I would be surprised if anyone remaps that one.

Comment: @ypnos Yep that is totally true, if another combination was mapped, the problem probably wouldn't occur. Having multiple depedencies and files, made me not post the script, otherwise it would have been easier..